# How to say, "I major in computer science" or "I'm studying computer science"?

Tags: translation, word-usage

”私はコンピューターサイエンスを勉強してます。” Do they use the term "computer science" in Japanese or is there a formal term for this?

Comment: Your sentence sounds fine ＾＾

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As well as コンピューターサイエンス, the terms コンピュータ科学 and [計算機科学]{けいさんきかがく} are also in use. They all refer to the term 'computer science' in English.

For majoring in something, you can say 専攻 or 専門. So,  専攻はコンピュータ科学です。or 専門はコンピュータ科学です。 Or insert the other terms instead.

Comment: There is also another word for computer science which is 情報工学. I asked a Japanese friend once if I should say コンピューターサイエンス or 情報工学 and he told me either way was correct. So I feel like there is no big difference between the two terms.